# Can't upload images to the server on mobile

Tags: php, html, image, mobile, upload

I am looking for any pointers what I am doing wrong here?

#### Situation:

I created a simple form on my [website](https://lmen.us/royalkitten/) that requires the user to enter some text data and an image. This information is then stored on the server - picture separately, and the text data in a `json` file.

I have tested it with multiple image formats on my desktop (I allow only the most common types, such as `jpg`, `png`, or `bmp`). All seems to be fine. However, it isn't so smooth on mobile (iOS). When I attempt to upload a screenshot (shows as a `png` format), or a picture I just took (`jpg`), the response that comes back says `Missing picture`, which means that no data was received on the server. The thing is that this is not always the case, some screenshots come through, some don't.

I am encoding the picture as a base64 string on the client. I tried logging it to make sure it goes through, and it seems to be fine. However, when I log the received parameters on the server, in these failed cases, the picture string is really empty! All I do is I read the `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` parameters (it's in PHP).

This error has been replicated only on mobile so far. On the front side, I guess this is the most relevant piece of code, but if you need more let me know! You can also inspect that website I included, but it will be slightly more difficult as it's minified.

```
function init_form_submit () {
  var button = document.getElementById('form-submit-btn'),
    image_upload_button = document.getElementById('picture');

  if (!button || !image_upload_button) return;

  image_upload_button.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    preview_image(this);
  });

  button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // Hijack the form submit.
    event.preventDefault();
    show_form_loader();

    var form_validator = FormValidator(GLOB.form_node);

    if (!form_validator.valid) {
      form_submitted_callback();
    }
    else {
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("about", form_validator.fd.about);
      formData.append("email", form_validator.fd.email || '');
      formData.append("handle", form_validator.fd.handle);
      formData.append("name", form_validator.fd.name);
      formData.append("picture", GLOB.picture);

      http.open('POST', 'https://lmen.us/royalkitten/api/apply-royal-kitten/index.php', true);
      http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
      http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var response;
        if (http.readyState !== 4 || http.status !== 200) return;
        try {
          response = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        }
        catch (error) {
          response = http.responseText;
          console.log(response);
        }
        form_submitted_callback(response);
      }
      http.send(formData);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is how I store the image data in the `GLOB.picture` variable. This function is called only twice - once in the code above when the user chooses an image, and once in a callback after a successful submission as a way to reset the form to its original state.

```
function preview_image (input) {
  var preview_label = document.getElementById('picture-label'),
    preview_element = document.getElementById('picture-preview');

  if (!input.files.length) {
    if (preview_label) {
      preview_label.innerHTML = 'Select a file';
    }

    if (preview_element) {
      preview_element.src = './images/image-placeholder-600x600.jpg';
    }

    GLOB.picture = null;
    return;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader(),
    file = input.files[0];

  if (!file) return;

  reader.onload = function (event) {
    var image_data = event.target.result;

    if (preview_label) {
      preview_label.innerHTML = file.name;
    }

    if (preview_element) {
      preview_element.src = image_data;
    }

    GLOB.picture = image_data;
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the problem is that your image is probably bigger than PHP max size allowed for a POST request. You should send your form as `multipart/form-data`, and send your image as a file. On the server side, you should get it via `$_FILE` instead of `$_POST`...

To send your image as a file, there are multiple solutions. First, you could send a base-64 encoded `Blob`, but it would be 30% larger than the original file (because of base-64 encoding).

What I would recommend to you is that you send the file in its original binary format, which is easier to implement and faster to upload.

To do so, you just need to send as-is the content of `input.files[0]`. let's say you set a `GLOB.pictureFile=input.files[0]` in your `preview_image()` function. you then just send it in the form like this :

```
formData.append("picture", GLOB.pictureFile);
```

Comment: Hm, I seem to be stuck elsewhere now. I changed the code slightly to use `multipart/form-data`, but now the `$_FILES` array is empty in the PHP code? I checked the phpinfo for maximum allowed file sizes, it's way above the image size.

Comment: are you sending a file in your form ? (not a base64 string)

Comment: Updated my friend! I am sending the picture encoded as you can see, when I check the headers of the sent request, it is there under the correct variable.

Comment: Sorry, what have you updated? I cannot see any change!

Comment: My answer... I updated and explained how to send as file.

Comment: Oh, I see now, thank you! I will have a go today or tomorrow!